# Can RadixSort be Ω(n log n)?

Tags: algorithm-analysis

I read about RadixSort and its time complexity and the worst best and average time Complexity is O(n) , so my question is can radixSort be Ω(n log n)?

Answer (score 6):

The more accurate time complexity analysis for  Radixsort gives time complexity as $O(kn)$-time where $k$ is number of digits, or keys (radix is defined as the base by which digits or keys are formed, hence the name radix sort).

For example, if you are given numbers 1 to $n$ in an unsorted list, then radix-sort will do the sorting in $O(n\log n)$ time.

So, radixsort can be $\Omega(n\log n)$ if you have $\Omega(\log n)$ digits in the numbers you are sorting.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort.

Answer (score 0):

If radix sort is implemented using counting sort as the auxiliary stable sort the analysis is as follows. Let $n$ be the numbers to be sorted, $d$ the number of digits in each input number and let the range of the digits be $0,1,\cdots,k$. Then the worst case running time is $O(d (n+k))$, so that when $k = O(n)$ the complexity is $O(dn)$. Assuming $d=O(1)$ the complexity is linear.

However the impact of the base used must be taken into account. Assume for instance that you want to sort $n$ base-10 numbers in the range $0,1,\cdots,R$. Then, the number of digits is $d = \lfloor \lg_{10} R \rfloor  + 1$ and the auxiliary storage array will need space for 10 cells. In each iteration you need to insert $n$ numbers into the 10 cells, so that the complexity is $O(n)$. The running time, in total, will be $O(dn) = O(\lg R \ n)$. Therefore when $n \approx R$ the complexity will be $O(R \lg R)$. This show that sorting using base-10 does not work for radix sort. Depending on the base used, the running time may even be bigger than $\Omega(n \ \lg n)$, e.g. it may be $\Omega(n^2)$.